# Syntax error - Wordpress

Tags: php

I wonder if anyone can help me,
I keep getting the following error on a WordPress theme

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND), expecting ')' in /var/sites/t/the-ldc.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/themes/creativ/inc/dynamic/static.css.php on line 123

if(!empty($smof_data['menu_reponsive_icon'] && $smof_data['header_layout'] == '1')){
            echo  "#zo-header #zo-menu-mobile i, #zo-header .menu-right #filter-menu {
                color:".esc_attr($smof_data['menu_reponsive_icon'])." !important;
            }\n"; 
        }

Comment: if(!empty($smof_data['menu_reponsive_icon'] && $smof_data['header_layout'] == '1')){
            echo  "#zo-header #zo-menu-mobile i, #zo-header .menu-right #filter-menu {
                color:".esc_attr($smof_data['menu_reponsive_icon'])." !important;             
            }\n"; 
        }

Answer (score 0):

Add the missing parenthesis after "icon']":

```
if(!empty($smof_data['menu_reponsive_icon']) && $smof_data['header_layout'] == '1'))
```

Comment: many thanks that fixed the error but now there is one on this line:        if(!empty($zo_meta->_zo_header_menu_reponsive_icon && !empty($zo_meta->_zo_header_layout == '1'))){
            echo  "#zo-header #zo-menu-mobile i, #zo-header .menu-right #filter-menu {
                  color:".esc_attr($zo_meta->_zo_header_menu_reponsive_icon)." !important; 
            }\n"; 
        }

perhaps I will contact the developer and ask them to update and check some of the code

Comment: Might be a good idea; I notice in your code in the comment, you put the parenthesis in the wrong spot ;)